# Volume Conservation in Shock Plastic Waves

Tags: waves, acoustics, continuum-mechanics, shock-waves

SOLIDS: Plastic deformation is known to have constant volume. During shock, does the plastic wave not compress the volume? Should the only compression come from the elastic wave?
Edit-1: screenshot

[image]

Comment: Plastic deformation is not known to have a constant volume. Constant volume is an **idealization** applied in many models of plastic deformation. Its suitability relies on the fact that the plastic flow strain is far larger than Poisson strains.

Comment: @Chemomechanics see my edit (insert why plastic def is, atomistically, constant volume). But are you saying that if the overall deformation is dominated by elastic deformation that then the overall volume is not constant? But still the plastic def part will have constant volume.

Comment: Yes, this can be a useful simplifying assumption. In reality, dislocations (with their accompanying surrounding stress fields) multiply, for example, so it isn’t a matter of a single defect moving between equivalent locations.

Comment: Thanks- so it’s physically false to assume plastic deformation is constant volume? Regardless of how large or small elastic deformations are relative to plastic deformation? Can you suggest any publications about this?

Comment: [Example](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0031918X1905017X); again, this aspect is often ignored in plasticity models. Please consider clarifying your question; it's not really clear what you're asking about.

Comment: Article helps thanks! So whether plastically deforming materials exhibit more excess volume or volume conservation depends whether there’s asymmetric lattice tension/compress i.e. nonlinear regions of plasticity. Which post-yield region on metal stress/strain curve has excess volume & by how much?